# Grabbing substrings with same start but variable end and lenght in a String an add it to an Array

Tags: java, string, arraylist, substring

I'm looking for a way to catch all substrings in a huge String. The substrings are all starting with:

> "productName":"  ,

after the quote right behind the colon, the substrings have obviously different endings and length, but they all have a quote like this on their very end:

> "productName":"cucumber" or "productName":"tomatoes"

I already tried by myself but with my code it stopped right after the first match (later I found out that is what `indexOf` does :D), how can I get every single substring and add it to the ArrayList ?

```
  ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
        String productName = "\"productName\":\"";
        String tmp = "";
        char endPoint =  '"';
        int lastIndex = unmodifiedSourceCode.indexOf(productName) + 15; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (unmodifiedSourceCode.charAt(lastIndex + i) != endPoint) {
                tmp += unmodifiedSourceCode.charAt(lastIndex + i);
            }
        }
        nameList.add(tmp);
```

I just started with Java.

EDIT: longer sample of the source code I'm working with

> "id":"483303","nan":"483303","version":59640,"productName":"cucumber","description":"detail":/PD1028378"}},"id":"1028378","nan":"1028378","version":27640,"productName":"bananas","description":

Comment: Looks like you're parsing JSON. You should consider using a library for that instead of treating whole key-value pairs as string.

Comment: @Mena beat me to it, but this sounds like an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/) about parsing JSON.

Comment: Leo A, can you give a couple of sample inputs and their corresponding outputs?

Comment: Please never add more information in comments. Always edit/update your question instead.

Comment: @GhostCat Ok sorry I will do it next time :)

Comment: Keep in mind: your question might sit here for years, and attract readers. So spare them the work of trying to read unreadable comments. Edit the question, add the json as well formatted text, and then delete the comment please ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it is a source code from a website, lokking like this "detail":"id":"483303","nan":"483303","version":59640,"productName":"cucumber","description":"detail":/PD1028378"}},"id":"1028378","nan":"1028378","version":27640,"productName":"bananas","description":

Java `String` class is a powerful class with lots of utility methods like indexOf or subString. You can extract the product name the following way:

```
    ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] tmpArray =  unmodifiedSourceCode.split("\"productName\":");
    for(int i=1; i < tmpArray.length; i++) {
        nameList.add(tmpArray[i].substring(1, tmpArray[i].indexOf("\"", 1)));
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. It is a source code so it doesn't stop after "productName":"cucumber" it goes one like in the sample I gave you and that [ ] stands for the arraylist I wanted to store all of the products in

Comment: @LeoA. That's precisely why I asked you to provide a couple of samples. I have updated my answer with your revised question.

Comment: I'm sorry, that was my first question, thank you very much that you updated it although I failed earlier.